# pass command line arguments to copy a file name in Java

Tags: java, file-io, command-line-arguments

Is it possible to write a program from an IDE (such as NetBeans or Eclipse) that can compile from the command line and run once the user enters two arguments just after the name of the java class program to run?

If so, can an absolute path be passed in as one of the arguments?

And if so, (if the source or destination file has a multi-word descriptor, like Big Sky File.txt), how can it be passed in as an argument?

I know this is a lot of questioning, but I have searched high and low and nothing seems to so much as scratch the surface on any of these topics.

@Code-Guru, @thkala, here's the code I am attempting (took a bit to format):

edit: @Code-Guru, I have added the offending line (not sure how I missed that).

next edit: @ Code-Guru, here is the updated file contents from CopyFile.java, and the resulting error message:

```
import java.io.*;

public class CopyFile
{
 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, NullPointerException
{ 
int num; 
FileInputStream fileIn; 
FileOutputStream fileOut; 
try
{ 
  // open input file 
  try
  { 
    fileIn = new FileInputStream(args[0]); 
  }

  catch(FileNotFoundException e)
  { 
  System.out.println("Input File Not Found."); 
  return; 
  }

  // open output file 
  try
  { 
    fileOut = new FileOutputStream(args[1]); 
  }

  catch(FileNotFoundException e)
  { 
    System.out.println("Error Opening Output File.");
    return;
  }

}

catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
{
  System.out.println("Incorrect argument use:java CopyFile Source Destination"); 
  return;
} 

// Copy File 
try
{ 
  do
  {
    num = fileIn.read();
    if(num != -1)
    {
      fileOut.write(num);
    }
  }

  while(num != -1); 
}

catch(IOException e)
{
  System.out.println("File Error: Could not copy file."); 
}
fileIn.close();
fileOut.close();
}
}
```

Here is the error message I receive from the command prompt:

> Error: Could not find or load main class CopyFile

Comment: Yes it is possible. I suggest that you google something like "command line arguments java". There is lots of information out there to help you get started. Feel free to come back when you have a specific question.

Comment: @Code-Guru Unfortunately, I have exhausted the resources at Google and on youtube. I've seen many snippets of information on how to pass command line arguments into a program, which I can do, but I am unsure why I cannot pass an absolute filename into a program I have written that I know exists, as I created it on my desktop. Should I be trying to focus more on relative paths? The reason I am asking these general questions is because the program I am running from the command line is throwing a java.lang.NoClassDefFound exception, and I am unsure as to why that is the case.

Comment: @user2155233: perhaps you should paste here an example of how you are calling your program. I suspect that you are messing up the quotation and in the process mangling the class name...

Comment: @user2155233 What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Code-Guru I have placed the code in the original post to see if it can be of use in determining where I made my error(s).

Comment: We also need an example of how you run your program as @thkala suggested. Also post the output when you run it.

Comment: @Code-Guru Here is the command from the command prompt that I run (in the original post) and the message I receive back from the command prompt.

Comment: @user2155233: Have you compiled your `.java` source code file with `javac` successfully (i.e. without errors)? Do you have the resulting `CopyFile.class` file in `C:\Users\name\Desktop\Copy File` ? Since you are not supplying a package name, `java` will try to find the class file in the current directory.

Comment: @thkala Hi, yes, the class file is in the same folder as the path directory, and I cannot think of other possible reasons for this error in the program. Both the CopyFile.java and CopyFile.class files are in a folder on the Desktop, and the directory I run the java Copyfile  program from is:

    C:\Users\name\Desktop\CopyFile>java CopyFile (arg0) (arg1)

The arg0 and arg1 are not in parentheses in the code, and are actual text file names such as the ones in the code above that resulted in an error. Should I change the classpath, or should I leave it to run Java from the default classpath too?

Comment: I want to point out that the code that you posted here differs from the code you compiled on your system. The code here is missing a `package` statement which is part of the problem as described in the answer from @Boann.

Comment: @Code-Guru I truly appreciate all the help that you have provided. I am left with an equally mystifying task of figuring out why I am still getting an error message from the command prompt, stating: "Error: Could not find or load main class CopyFile" (error message not in quotes) I know the CopyFile.java and CopyFile.class files are in a folder called CopyFile on the desktop, and I have removed the package copyfile; statement from the top of the code. Also, the two arguments I am looking to pass to the program, Basic.txt and Empty.txt, are also within the CopyFile folder.

Comment: @user2155233 Did you recompile with `javac` after removing the `package` statement? If so and you still get the error, try deleting the .class file and compile again. If *that* still doesn't fix the error, edit your question to show the latest version of your code and what the error message is (if it is different).

Comment: @Code-Guru I have removed the package statement, deleted the old CopyFile.class file (and emptied the Recycling Bin), closed the Command Prompt and re-opened it, switched the directory back to the "C:\Users\name\Desktop\CopyFile>" path, re-run the compiler with the javac command on the CopyFile.java file, and run the resultant CopyFile.class file, passing in the arguments as was previously done. I will update the initial question and resulting error message as soon as I finish typing this comment.

Comment: @user2155233 Please post the rest of the error message up to the first line that starts with "at".

Comment: @Code-Guru Unfortunately, this was the entirety of the error message that I received from the Command Prompt.

Comment: It sounds like java can't find your .class file at all now...

Comment: @Code-Guru I do have one thought that occurred to me: should it matter that I am running an IDE (Eclipse) that a similar version of the code (the only difference is that includes the package copyfile; statement) is available in another folder in a separate directory (the directory for Eclipse .class files)?

edit: I finally found the root problem: the classpath was set to the same folder that the jdk was set to, so it automatically looked there instead of the current directory.

I truly thank everyone for all their help, this was most perplexing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies in this part of the error message:

```
(wrong name: copyfile/CopyFile)
```

I.e., your class's fully qualified name is `copyfile.CopyFile`. Java requires that the package layout match the folder layout on disk so it knows how to find things.

So either your class file must be in a subfolder called `copyfile`, and then invoked as `java copyfile.CopyFile`, or you can compile your class in the unnamed default package by removing the `package copyfile;` declaration from the code (you haven't shown that line, but it must be there).

More info: http://www.jarticles.com/package/package_eng.html

Comment: Thanks! I removed the package statement from the top of the code using a text editor (Notepad++), but now I get an error message simply stating: "Error: Could not find or load main class CopyFile" (error message not in quotes)

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to write a program from an IDE (such as NetBeans or Eclipse) that can compile from the command line and run once the user enters two arguments just after the name of the java class program to run?

Yes, it is possible.

> If so, can an absolute path be passed in as one of the arguments?

Definitely - [any string can be passed as an argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html), as long as its size does not exceed a certain (usually system-defined) limit.

> And if so, (if the source or destination file has a multi-word descriptor, like Big Sky File.txt), how can it be passed in as an argument?

Typically, arguments with spaces, special characters e.t.c. are handled by the calling shell, rather than the Java program. Consult your documentation on how to properly quote such arguments in whatever command line shell you are using.